# Reuse implemented business classes in a web applications

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets

I have implemented my domain layer classes and i have used them in a java application.
Now i want to use same classes in a java web application,but i don't know how can i do it?
In the java application we make and run some objects in main(class and method) and use them while program is running.
for example an object that hold a collection of data that will be needed for all user requests.
My question is:
How can i create and hold such objects and data that should be available  for all users and clients.

Answer (score 1):

Place them in the application context. I.e. in a `Servlet` call `getServletContext().setAttribute("name", yourCollection);`

Then they can be retrieved by `getServletContext().getAttribute("name")`

Comment: The [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) may be useful to load (and destroy) the data in question during webapp's startup (and shutdown).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a singleton which represents the common application logic, initialising and cleaning up the common information and objects on web-app startup and shutdown.

All servkets can use the application singleton to retrieve and store.

To initialise and cleanup on web-app startup and shutdown you can define an administrative servlet which has the load-on-startup flag set in the deployment descriptor web.xml managing the application singleton from the `init()` and `destroy()` methods.